# $\pi$ is just a number, or also the circumference of a sub-unit circle?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, circles, pi

A unit circle defined in the Cartesian plane has a radius of $1$ and a diameter of $2$. So making a full round is $2 \pi$. Now, $\pi$ is the ratio of the circumference over the diameter, so if I have a circle with diameter $1$ (radius $0\mathord{,}5$), the circumference would be $\pi$ because its $c/d = c/1$ must equal $\pi$. Hence $c= \pi$. So $\pi$ is actually the circumference of a "subunit" circle? or I am missing something here?

Comment: Yes, $\pi$ is the circumference of a circle of diameter $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing yourself by talking about two different circles, but you are correct that $\pi$ is the circumference of a circle of radius $0.5$.

---

For a circle of radius $1$, we have
$$r\text{ (radius)}=1\qquad d\text{ (diameter)}=2\qquad c\text{ (circumference)}=2\pi$$
The ratio of the circumference to the diameter is
$$\frac{c}{d}=\frac{2\pi}{2}=\pi.$$

---

For a circle of radius $0.5$, we have
$$r\text{ (radius)}=0.5\qquad d\text{ (diameter)}=1\qquad c\text{ (circumference)}=\pi$$
The ratio of the circumference to the diameter is
$$\frac{c}{d}=\frac{\pi}{1}=\pi.$$

---

Comment: why? If I have a circle with diameter 1 then the circonference should equal π ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So its true, the circumference is equal to π of a circle with 0.5 radius. Weard thing is that π never ends and it is an irational number but if I unwrap the circumference to a line it does end :D. Anyway thanx, I needed some confirmation on this

Comment: The *decimal expansion* of $\pi$ does not end, and $\pi$ is an irrational number. Just because a line segment of length $\pi$ "comes to an end" doesn't imply anything about writing the number down as a decimal.

Comment: And why is that? Is it that my line will be incomplete or incorect or a simple aproximation against the true value of π?

Comment: @themhz : The definition of "irrational number" is _not_ a number that never ends, nor is it a number whose decimal expansion never ends.  It is true that the decimal expansion of an irrational number never ends, and also that the decimal expansions of some _rational_ numbers never end.  But the definition of the concept of irrational number never mentions decimal expansions at all.  An irrational number is, by definition, a number that is not a quotient of two integers.

Comment: @themhz: There's nothing incomplete or incorrect about the line, but there *is* an approximation issue. Having un-wrapped a circumference, it's reasonable to measure it with a *ruler* marked off in equal "circle-diameter" units; the un-wrapped circumference ends somewhere between the "3" mark and the "4" mark on that ruler. So, you sub-divide the ruler with more equally-spaced marks ... say, at every 1/10th of a unit; the circumference will end somewhere between the "3.1" mark and the "3.2" mark. So, more equally-spaced marks, and more marks, and more ... you'll *just miss* $\pi$ every time.

Comment: @themhz: (con't) On the other hand, trying to measure the circle's diameter with a ruler marked at circumference-length units, the diameter's end falls somewhere between "0" and "1". Sub-dividing the new ruler at every 1/10 of a (circumference) unit, the diameter ends between "0.3" and "0.4", and so on and so forth ... A circumference-based ruler (with equally-spaced sub-divisions) can never *precisely* measure the diameter, just as a diameter-based ruler (with equally-spaced sub-divisions) can never *precisely* measure the circumference. The lengths are "incommensurate". (Look it up. :)